# b-table cell cliked event missing

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have to pass cell value to the function clicking on the cell. It can be done easily on good table, but I am trying to find the way do it on bootstrap-vue b-table.

table:

```
<b-table
    striped
    responsive
    class="mb-0"
    :items="permissionsData"
  >
    <template #cell(module)="data">
      {{ data.value }}
    </template>
    <template
      #cell()="data"
    >
      <b-form-checkbox
        :checked="data.value"
      />
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

and the method:

```
methods: {
    onPermissionClick(value) {
        console.log("column name, row name and the value")
    }
},
```

Is anyone know good way how to do that please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<b-table
    striped
    responsive
    class="mb-0"
    :items="permissionsData"
  >
    <template #cell(module)="data">
       <div @click="onPermissionClick">
            {{ data.value }}
       </div>
    </template>
  </b-table>
```

You will get all property in the data. but here I am mentioning cell, row, and column as per your question. other property you can see by console.log(data)

```
methods: {
    onPermissionClick(data) {
       console.log(data.value)   // cell value
        console.log(data.item)   // row
        console.log(data.field) // column
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that dose not work.

Comment: It should be <div @click=onPermissionClick(data)">

Comment: Thanks @NikolaGava.
forgot to pass data in params.